# Problems Accessing dictionary in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am able to access the dictionary fine in my django python shell by using `p['cover']['source']`. I can also access the 'source' in the templates using the dot notation, however, when attempting to access `p['cover']['source']` in my views I get a keyError. I was able to access the 'cover' using `p.get('cover','none')` but I need to get `p['cover']['source']` and I have no idea how to access this. Please help :-)

```
  views.py
  image_table = []
       for n in likes:
       link = n.facebook_id
       p = graph.get_object(str(link))
       #image = p['cover']['source'] //This returns KeyError
       #image = p['cover'][0]['source'] //This returns KeyError = 0
       image = p.get('cover','none')//This only returns the first dictionary
       image_table.append(image)
```

Comment: You can't access something that is not there. Find out why it is not being set wherever it is supposed to be.

Comment: But my confusion is because it is there. For example, if I access p['cover'] like that it fails but p.get('cover','none') works. Also if  I can access the dictionary from the template but not from views. That doesn't make sense to me so I'm struggling to find where it's set

Comment: Possibly it is not a dictionary but a dict-like object.

Comment: If it helps the dictionary is being returned from the Facebook GraphAPI.

Comment: What are the contents of `image` when you do `p.get('cover','none')`? Is it a dictionary? What are its keys?

Comment: Yes, I am passed back a dictionary. This the first record passed back from the list I append it to:{'source': 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/64624_10150775399452788_2010622991_n.jpg', 'cover_id': '10150775399452788', 'offset_x': 0, 'offset_y': 14}

Comment: Is it possible that not all users have a cover picture and those fail with KeyError? Put `image = p['cover']['source']` in a `try/except` block and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you @PauloAlmeida that seemed to be the issue, I wasn't catching the errors and it was causing the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some users may not have a cover picture, causing the `KeyError` when you access the dictionary. Use a try/except block to prevent the error:

```
try:
    image = p['cover']['source']
except KeyError:
    pass  # or other alternative for those without cover picture
```